# How to search through a string and extract the required value in unix

Tags: string, bash, unix, search, cut

I have a string like below

```
QUERY_RESULT='88371087|COB-A#2014-04-22,COB-C#2014-04-22,2014-04-22,2014-04-23 88354188|COB-W#2014-04-22,2014-04-22,2014-04-22 88319898|COB-X#2014-04-22,COB-K#2014-04-22,2014-04-22,2014-04-22'
```

This is a result taken by querying the database. Now I want to take all the values before the pipe and separate it with coma. So the output needed is :

```
A='88371087,88354188,88319898'
```

The db values can be different every time, there can be just one value or 2 or more values
How do I do it.

Comment: How did you get this information from the query? maybe an array would be cleaner. Can you show us the query statement explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk

```
A=`echo $QUERY_RESULT | awk '{ nreg=split($0,reg);for(i=1;i<=nreg;i++){split(reg[i],fld,"|");printf("%s%s",(i==1?"":","),fld[1]);}}'`

echo $A

88371087,88354188,88319898
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep -oP`

```
grep -oP '(^| )\K[^|]+' <<< "$QUERY_RESULT"
88371087
88354188
88319898
```

OR to get comma separated value:

```
A=$(grep -oP '(^| )\K[^|]+' <<< "$QUERY_RESULT"|sed '$!s/$/,/'|tr -d '\n')
echo "$A"
88371087,88354188,88319898
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ words=( $( grep -oP '\S+(?=\|)' <<< "$QUERY_RESULT") )
$ A=$(IFS=,; echo "${words[*]}")
$ echo "$A"
88371087,88354188,88319898
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash only.

```
shopt -s extglob

result=${QUERY_RESULT//|+([^ ]) /,}
result=${result%|*}

echo  "$result"
```

Output:

```
88371087,88354188,88319898
```